# themify google map api key error

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I have installed themify WordPress theme and created a home page in it locally. Google map is giving the following error in JavaScript console.

```
util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keysTA.j @ util.js:210(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:126(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98hc @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:45gc.wb @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98(anonymous function) @ stats.js:1
util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-requiredTA.j @ util.js:210(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:126(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98hc @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:45gc.wb @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:98(anonymous function) @ stats.js:1
VM23938:1 'webkitIDBTransaction' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBTransaction' instead.(anonymous function) @ VM23938:1a.S @ VM23904:1V @ VM23904:1F @ VM23904:1botguard.bg @ VM23904:1(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:123g @ www-embed-player.js:108
js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:34 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.kb @ js?sensor=false&ver=4.6.1:34(anonymous function) @ common.js:50(anonymous function) @ common.js:203c @ common.js:44(anonymous function) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Frdxcorporate%2Faffiliate-clubs%2F&cal…:1
```

I am unable to find the location where I can put the api key.

Answer (score 1):

[This has been documented](https://themify.me/known_issues/google-map-not-working) in the Themify documentation:

> Google recently requires users to create an API key in order to use
>   Google Map. To fix this go to
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key,
>   then copy your API key and paste it in Themify > Settings > Google
>   Maps page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The option Themify>Settings>Google Maps Page is not available there. I have searched the whole theme but unable to find the option

Comment: Then you should contact Themify about this - it may depend of the themify theme you purchased.

Comment: Any one Please help?

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz We don't provide support for premium theme that we can't obviously test. You have to contact your support for this, providing your purchase info: https://themify.me/forum